# How can I install the minimap plugin for vi or vim?

Tags: vim, plugins, text-editor, vi

## My System

1. Ubuntu Desktop 18.04 LTS
2. Window Manager: i3WM
3. No virtualization.
4. Native install.

*Parts of this question comes from [my post on Facebook](https://www.facebook.com/groups/GNUAndLinux/permalink/10163550640005019/)*

Some days ago I was trying to identify this terminal text editor because of the plugins which are available on the left and right sidebars:

[image]

So far we have identified that the editor is `vi` and  I have successfully installed `nerdtree` plugin as it shows in the left sidebar, it was suggested in the comments of my Facebook post. Now I am looking for a way to install the minimap on the right. Maybe it is a plugin or something.

Any ideas?

Screenshots were added from my own desktop. Please notice that I am a i3WM user and I am using Yakuake as my terminal emulator.

**NOTE**

I guess this is the minimap https://github.com/severin-lemaignan/vim-minimap but I can't find a way to install in Ubuntu.

### Screenshots from my Desktop

[image]

[image]

### Update

This is what happens when I press <kbd>i</kbd> after selecting the `Plugin 'severin-lemaignan/vim-minimap'` inside the Plugin Installer from whithin `vim`

[image]

Comment: Are you sure that first screenshot contains Vi? If it is Emacs, then *minimap* came from [*elpa-minimap*](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/elpa-minimap) package.

Comment: @K7AAY I added the information you requested. Thank you

Comment: @N0rbert: The other screenshots are from my desktop, they do look similar to the first one, except for the Window Manager, Tiling Window or whatever they are using. So we can say it is `vi`, anyway, my question is about `vi` which seems to have such `minimap` also but I can't find a way to install it. Thank you

Comment: The Readme for Minimap https://github.com/severin-lemaignan/vim-minimap/blob/master/README.md has three options: Vundle https://github.com/VundleVim/Vundle.vim/blob/master/README.md , Janus https://janus.conf.meetecho.com/docs/index.html , and AUR.  The latter is Arch Linux specific, so we can rule that out.  Janus is a WebRTC server  and looks much more complex than Vundle. Suggest you look into Vundle.

Comment: I posted a screen update. Thank you

Comment: Thank you guys. Your ideas and comments helped me a lot to understand  what I had to do and gave me the proper keywords to look for on the net. That's how I found a way and have written my own manual to fix this. Thank you very much!

Comment: Consider switching from Vundle, which hasn't been very well maintained, to vim-plug, which is a more modern successor for it. vim-plug is similar to Vundle, so it's an easy upgrade (mostly replace "Plug" for Plugin, also in the commands.) It's more featureful and efficient too.

Comment: Hey! @filbranden, thank you for the suggestion. Just a couple of questions here: 1.- Does vim-plug have the same support for the minimap I need? 2.- Can vim-plug co-exist with Vundle? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @GeppettvsD'Constanzo 1. Yes, surely! 2. Possibly, but not recommended. See [this page](https://github.com/junegunn/vim-plug/wiki/tips#migrating-from-other-plugin-managers) for instructions on how to migrate from Vundle to vim-plug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution on this page: https://linuxhint.com/vim-vundle-tutorial/

I had to remove (purge) vim and everything related to whatever I did before, and start again following the instructions provided in this (and other pages which I'll refer to later), that's how I ended up with this manual, which I share here for the convenience of some people who may wish to do this from scratch.

#### **Installing Vundle**

First, you have to install Git version control system. It is available on the official package repository of any Linux distributions. I will use Debian 9 Stretch for this article.

#### **For Ubuntu, Debian, Linux Mint and other Debian based distros:**

Update the package repository cache with the following command:

```
$ sudo apt-get update
```

[image]

Then install Git with the following command:

```
$ sudo apt install git -y
```

Git should be installed, upgraded or if you already have the newest version, you'll receive a message saying git is already the newest version.

[image]

> *Note: I am keeping this for compatibility with other Linux Systems.*

#### **For Fedora, RHEL, CentOS:**

To install Git on Fedora, RHEL and CentOS, run the following commands:

```
$ yum makecache
$ sudo yum install git -y
```

Now you can install VIM with the following command:

```
$ sudo apt-get install vim -y
```

VIM should be installed. In my case, it’s already installed on my system.

[image]

> *Note: I am keeping this for compatibility with other Linux Systems.*

For Fedora, RHEL, CentOS, run the following command to install VIM:

```
$ sudo yum install vim -y
```

Now go to the official website of Vundle at https://github.com/VundleVim/Vundle.vim

You should see the following page.

[image]

Now click on “Clone or download” button as marked red on the screenshot below. A popup window should appear. Click on the icon as marked blue in the screenshot. The git repository URL should be copied.

[image]

Now open up a Terminal and run the following command:

```
$ git clone PASTE_URL_HERE ~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim
```

After pasting the URL, the command should look like this:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/VundleVim/Vundle.vim.git ~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim
```

[image]

The Github repository should be cloned in the ‘.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim’ directory in the USER’s home directory.

[image]

Now run the following command:

```
vim ~/.vimrc
```

Or if you prefer you can use nano:

```
nano ~/.vimrc
```

It should open `.vimrc` file with VIM. If `.vimrc` file doesn’t exist, an empty file should be opened.

[image]

In my case, I already have an existing `.vimrc` file.

[image]

Now go to the end of the `.vimrc` file and press

[image]

Now add the following lines as shown in the screenshot below. Then save and exit vim with VIM command `:wq!`

Now add the following lines as shown in the screenshot below. Then save and exit vim with VIM command `:wq!`

```
set nocompatible  
filetype off  
set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim  
call vundle#begin()  
Plugin 'VundleVim/Vundle.vim'  

" Add plugins here  

call vundle#end()  
filetype plugin indent on
```

[image]

Now open vim.

[image]

[image]

Run the following VIM command to initialize Vundle Plugin Manager:

```
:PluginInstall
```

[image]

The Vundle plugin should be installed.

[image]

#### **Searching and Installing Plugin using Vundle Plugin Manager:**

You can search for VIM plugins using Vundle Plugin Manager.

Let’s say you want to install a color scheme for VIM. Run the following VIM command to search for all the available VIM colorscheme plugins.

```
:PluginSearch colorscheme
```

[image]

You should see a lot of colorscheme plugins as shown in the screenshot below.

[image]

I am going to install `Royal-Colorschemes`.

To install a plugin, just move the VIM cursor to the line and press <kbd>i</kbd>

[image]

The plugin should be installed.

[image]

Now copy the line.

[image]

Paste it in the `.vimrc` file in the section as shown in the screenshot below.

[image]

#### **Listing Installed Plugins:**

You can also list all the installed VIM plugins with the following VIM command:

`:PluginList`

[image]

You can see that I have 2 plugins installed right now.

[image]

#### **Installing a Plugin from Github using Vundle Plugin Manager:**

You can install a plugin from Github repository as well. Let’s say you want to install ‘powerline’ from the Github repository of powerline.

Go to the Github page of powerline and copy the project author/name section as marked in the screenshot below.

[image]

Open the `.vimrc` file and type in the following line in the marked section.

`Plugin ‘GITHUB_REPO_USER/GITHUB_REPO_PROJECT_NAME’`

[image]

Then save the file and exit out of VIM.

Now start VIM and run the following VIM command to install the plugin using Vundle Plugin Manager.

`:PluginInstall`

[image]

Powerline plugin should be installed as shown in the screenshot below.

[image]

You can list the available plugins with `:PluginList` command.

[image]

You should be able to see ‘powerline’ there.

[image]

#### **Removing a Plugin using Vundle Plugin Manager:**

You can also remove a Plugin using Vundle Plugin Manager.

First run ‘:PluginList’ command to list all the installed VIM plugins.

[image]

These are the plugins I have installed right now.

[image]

Let’s delete ‘powerline’ plugin. To delete powerline plugin, just move your cursor to the line and press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>

[image]

The plugin should be deleted.

[image]

Now open `.vimrc` file again, remove the marked line for powerline and save the file.

[image]

`.vimrc` file with powerline plugin line removed.

[image]

That’s it.

So that’s how you use VIM Vundle Plugin Manager to manage VIM plugins easily. Thanks for reading this article.

## Installing Minimap

After following the tutorial above, I simply followed the instructions provided in the README.MD file of **A code minimap for Vim** at https://github.com/severin-lemaignan/vim-minimap

### Vundle

> With vundle, simply add: `Plugin 'severin-lemaignan/vim-minimap'` to
>   your .vimrc and run :PluginInstall from vim.

## Installing The NERDTree

The instructions provided in the README.markdown file for NERDTree in order to install it, is as easy as placing the next line in the `.vimrc` file.

```
Plugin 'preservim/nerdtree'
```

The same file provides a way to make it permanent and open automatically when you run `vim`, you just need to place this into your `.vimrc` file:

```
autocmd StdinReadPre * let s:std_in=1
autocmd VimEnter * if argc() == 0 && !exists("s:std_in") | NERDTree | endif
```

## My additions

I added the next lines to my .vimrc file in order to always show the Minimap, the line numbers and to provide mouse compatibility when editing.

```
au BufEnter * :Minimap
au BufEnter * :set number
au BufEnter * :set mouse=a
```

## That's it!

Now my vim looks like this.

[image]
Vertical monitor

[image]
Horizontal (laptop) monitor

Answer (score 1):

First, make sure that the line: `Plugin 'severin-lemaignan/vim-minimap'` is not repeated in your `~/.vimrc` file.

However, other users have reported this issue with no repeated lines. I think I found [a fix for this](https://github.com/VundleVim/Vundle.vim/issues/509#issuecomment-87740162-permalink). You need to edit your `~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim/autoload/vundle/config.vim` file. Run the following command to make the change:

```
sed -i '95i\    \\ && s:bundle_names[a:bundle.name]!=a:bundle.name_spec' ~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim/autoload/vundle/config.vim
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I ended up removing everything and re-doing from scratch. I will have this in mind for later usage if needed.

Comment: It seems this happens when more than one plugin uses the same "short name".